# Light's wavelength and pathlength

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, wavelength

I see this 2 words (wavelength and path length) used interchangeably.

As interpreted here: 'The total power density arriving at the surface depends on the absorption path length of the light travelling through the atmosphere.' (then shows a graph of spectral irradiance vs wavelength)

According to my understanding, wavelength is the distance between successive crests of a wave and path length is the distance overall length of the path followed by a light ray.

How are they related?

For e.g. 'at the equator, the light has the smallest path length through the atmosphere.', what has the smallest wavelength (which is also path length) got to do with distance to the equator?

I got a feeling I am misunderstanding something here. Any explanation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be seeing those words used interchangably. They are totally different concepts.

The path length is how far the light travelled to get from one place to another. If there's a light bulb over there 10 m away, and you're standing here, the path length is 10 m. If a light is shone into a piece of optical fiber and 10 km of fiber is spooled up on the bench and the light comes out the other end, the path length is 10 km, even though the source and destination are only a few meters apart. Neither of these depend on what the wavelength of the light is.

The wavelength is, like you say, the distance between minima or maxima of the electric field in the wave. For things that we call "light" this is usually somewhere in the range of 100 nm to 10 um. If you make a 632.8 nm HeNe laser, the output wavelength will be 632.8 nm, no matter how long a path you propagate the beam through. If you shine the beam into a piece of glass, the wavelength changes (because the frequency remains the same but the propagation velocity slows down) but once it exits the glass again, the original wavelength is restored.

> at the equator, the light has the smallest path length through the atmosphere.', what has the smallest wavelength (which is also path length) got to do with distance to the equator?

It means either the atmosphere is thinner around the equator, or something about the setup means the beam will be directed in a more vertical direction when the experiment is done at the equator.

It has nothing to do with the wavelength, and the wavelength is not the same thing as the path length.

**Edit**

For the case of spectral irradiance, the result depends on both path length and wavelength. Path length because if light from the sun passes through a taller column of atmosphere, more of it will be absorbed before reaching the ground. Wavelength because different molecules in the atmosphere will absorb different wavelengths more or less.

So you should actually have a plot of spectral irradiance vs wavelength at the equator, and at each latitude up to the poles, with different path lengths through the atmosphere at each latitude.